# $1/x + 1/x^2 + 1/x^3+ \cdots +1/x^n = y$, how to find value of $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives

The expression is a geometric series

$1/x + 1/x^2 + 1/x^3...+1/x^n = y$ (which is known value)

P.S. $X$ denotes rate of interest per month and $y$ = loan/monthly payment.
The interest rate would be the interest rate customer is paying to the lender

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a geometric sum.

$$1+r+r^2+\cdots + r^n = \dfrac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

So, plugging in $r=\dfrac{1}{x}$ gives:

$$y-1 = \dfrac{1-\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\dfrac{1}{x}}$$

Simplifying:

$$0 = (y-2)x^{n+1}-(y-1)x^n+1$$

This polynomial does not have a simple solution in $x$, although if you plug in $n$ and $y$, you can get a solution using a computer algebra system.

Comment: I do not get how you simplified the equation, I get $(y-1)(x-1)x^{n}=x^{n+1}-1$

Comment: Oops, I did the reciprocal. I fixed it.

Comment: InterstellarProbe thank you, Any sites that you may suggest where I can plug in values for y and n and get x back. I tried .symbolab.com but it says it cannot calculate the value.

Comment: I use wolframalpha